# All my dwarves are bleeding to death. What can I do?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

After a relatively short battle with a forgotten beast, in which none of my militia were injured, everyone in my fortress has started dropping dead. Even dwarves that were not involved in the battle have started spontaneously bleeding to death.

[image: The Dwarves are all bleeding to death!]

The forgotten beast was described as having "noxious secretions", which I'm assuming is the cause of my current problems.

Is there anything that I can do to save my dwarves?

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself: Is their violent demise sufficiently awesome to count as FUN?

Comment: i assume you already have a hospital going? if not look here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31918/can-i-force-treatment-of-my-dwarves/31957#31957
 but im honestly not sure if it will help you. :S

Comment: @Hackworth yes, this definitely counts as a _fun_ way for my fortress to go belly up. I was hoping for for one more goblin siege to test out my new trap corridor, we'll see if I can get any dwarves to last that long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they walk through some shallow running water, it will wash off any FB blood/secretions. It won't help the ones who are already affected, but it should save those who aren't yet. I haven't yet had to do this myself, but I've read that it works.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I did try and set up a goblin drowning pit earlier, but it only ended up giving them all a bath since I couldn't pump water in fast enough...maybe I've finally found a use for it.

Comment: Perfect! Just set it as your meeting area, and all your dwarves will head there for a bath.

Comment: That seems to have worked. I set up a burrow in the shallow water and made all the dwarves go there. Although now I'm having to deal with the ensuing tantrum spiral. Do you remember where you read you read about this?

Comment: I read it on the Forgotten Beast page on the DF wiki, [here](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Forgotten_beast). Sigh... apparently quoting doesn't work particularly well. It's in the second paragraph, the one which talks about venom.

Comment: This method also works if for some bizarre reason your dwarves start complaining about being too filthy. Shallow water, waterfalls and rain will all do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need a hospital, doctor, and bandages.

Comment: I have a hospital set up, however, the dwarves are dropping dead before they can get anywhere close. In any case, they haven't even sustained any injuries, so I'm not sure if they would even go to the hospital for diagnosis.